# Getting NPE error while populating JTable from 2-D array

Tags: java, swing, jtable, apache-poi

I've been facing NPE error while populating JTable from xlsx file using XSSFSheet of Apache POI.
Although I was successful at fetching rows from excel sheet into a 2D array but can't populate that Jtable from 2D array. (Codes below)

## 2D Array Population

```
private void populateTable() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Pool.xlsx"));
    ExcelToArray obj = new ExcelToArray(file);
    header = obj.getHeader(); //1d array-data present
    data = obj.getTableData(); //2d array-data present 
    file.close();
}
```

## User Interface

```
public void initUI(){
    screen= new JFrame();
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    screen.setContentPane(contentPane);
    table = new JTable(data, header); //getting NPE error here
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    contentPane.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    screen.setVisible(true);
}
```

## Methods calling Hierarchy

```
public MainPage() throws IOException { //Constructor
    populateTable();
    initUI();
}
```

## Error Details

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.JTable$1.getColumnName(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.addColumn(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
at MainPage.initUI(MainPage.java:103)
at MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:62)
at MainPage.main(MainPage.java:52)
```

Please help and guide what is wrong with my approach. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get a NPE, then check whether one of the involved objects is null. In your case `data`and `header`. Also, if you wants help, so show the stack trace of the error you got.

Comment: Thank you, Axel, but I checked and both "data" and "header" arrays are having data. 
Updated my question for error details.

Comment: It would be enough if one of the array elements of `header` would be null or if one of the sub arrays of  `data` would be null. Show the stack trace!

Comment: If  `javax.swing.JTable$1.getColumnName` throws NPE, then one of the array elements of `header` is null. So one column name is null.

Comment: It worked, actually many elements in both the arrays were null but when I reduced the array size it worked. Thanks once again